# Firebase Auth token to test it in Postman in Javascript and & Angualar

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I have written the code for firebase auth. I want the firebase auth token to test it in my Postman. but I don't know how to get it.
Here is the code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, user }  from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { getIdToken } from 'firebase/auth';
import { User } from 'firebase/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor( private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router ) { }

  //login Method
  login(email: string, password: string) {
    var credientials = this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then( () => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', 'true');


      //i think this is the funciton which should accept the arguments for the token but don't know how to made this possibe.
      // getIdToken();

      this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
    }, err => {
      alert('Something went wrong');
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    })
  }
```

Please tell me what should i write or what changes should i make. I have attached the reference image for a better understanding of what token I want.
[image]